# how to fix omit the close tag without modify original code?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code like this

```
<div class="footer"><p>some text<p></div>
```

as you can see closing tag for p is omit.
how can I fix that without edit original code?
I think JavaScript can do this.

Comment: What does "fix" look like? Should the result be `<p>some text</p>` or `<p>some text</p><p></p>`?

Comment: No, I want to close only one p. there's not another p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just modify the innerHTML of the footer element.

```
var footer = document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0];
footer.innerHTML = "<p>some text</p>";
```

This will replace the content in the footer.

Comment: Have you tried that? I get `<p>some text</p><p></p>`.

Comment: yeah this works fine for me. You can just try it in the google console by pressing strg + shift + i

If you are using this in html, you need to use the <script></script> tag arround it.

Comment: @Sly321 FYI, some browsers auto close tags so the code in there is `<p>some text</p><p></p>` before your bit of JavaScript even runs, which is why RobG has got his outcome...

Comment: The `<p>` tag doesn't require a closing tag, so **all** (standards compliant) browsers will convert `<p><p>` to two paragraph elements, which will be serialised back into `<p></p><p></p>` by the *innerHTML* property.

Answer (score 2):

```
var div = document.querySelector('div.footer'); // get div element
Array.prototype.forEach.call(div.childNodes, function(childNode){ // for every element inside of div
    if (childNode.innerHTML === '') { // check if that element is empty
        div.removeChild(childNode); // remove that element
    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/soygb9cs/

It works because modern browsers automatically closes tags. So you get one additional empty tag if you omit backslash in closing tag.

From `<div><p>some text<p></div>`  browser creates `<div><p>some text</p><p></p></div>`

Comment: +1. There are a bunch of elements that don't require closing tags and never have, such as TR, TD, LI, OPTION and others), so not only "modern browsers" will turn `<p><p>` into two paragraphs. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript *can* do that, however because JavaScript runs after the page has loaded, your web page will still be classed as W3C invalid (https://validator.w3.org/).

If you just have lots of HTML with this error and you're trying to save yourself some manual labour, I suggest using something like [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Copy your HTML into a new document and do a regular expression find and replace like so:

[image: Find & Replace in Notepad++]

Comment: I only have one html with that error, but for some reason I haven't enough permission to modify it.

Comment: Then I suggest you either find someone that does have the permission, or try and get the permission yourself. Using JavaScript to do this is a _very_ hack and trashy way of doing it.

Comment: "*…classed as W3C invalid…* nope. If you actually try the code in the validator, you'll find it's valid HTML (and has been since there was an HTML standard).

Comment: @RobG "_has been since there was an HTML standard_" - not quite. If you use a `XHTML 1.0 Strict` Doctype it will stick it's middle finger up at you. This question is a perfect example of why the new HTML5 standard for close tags not being needed is crap, you can end up with extra tags and extra white space on your page that is unwanted not needed.

Comment: @JamieBarker—XHTML is not HTML. That experiment is over.